# How to pass res/raw/a01.wav file in this scenario

Tags: android

i have stored all my audio files in res/raw.  now i want to feed it to the below function

```
 public void audioPlayer(raw raduio) {

        MediaPlayer mp5 = new MediaPlayer();

        try {


            mp5.setDataSource(); //how to feed raduio here ?
            mp5.prepare();
            mp5.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            mp5.reset();
        }
    }
```

how to do it?
how to send the R.raw.a01 as parameter in the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code [wavId - R.raw.a01]:

```
public void audioPlayer(raw raduio, int wavId) {

    MediaPlayer mp5 = new MediaPlayer();

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mContext.getResources().openRawResourceFd(wavId);

    try {


        mp5.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor()));
        mp5.prepare();
        mp5.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        mp5.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can put R.raw.filename instead of audioResource id

Comment: how to send the R.raw.a01 as parameter in the method?

Comment: it is takking integer value so you can put R.raw.a01

Comment: mp5.setDataSource(fd); or afd?

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use this

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create( MainActivity.this,  R.raw.song1 );
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener( new OnCompletionListener()
 {
   @Override
     public void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mp )
       {
          mp.release();
        }
  } );
  mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: you can skip completion listener